# i want to make a java program to search files with name containing "xyz" and all files having "xyz" string pattern in them

Tags: java, out-of-memory

the recursivePrint function will display for files and folders recursively there i have called a function to search a word in a file 
this code works for small no. of files 
but when i use all directory it gives outofmemoryerror java heap space

```
File[] maindir = File.listRoots();

for(int i = 0; i < maindir.length ; i++) {

        if (maindir[i].exists() && maindir[i].listFiles() != null) {
            // array for files and sub-directories
            // of directory pointed by maindir

            File arr[] = maindir[i].listFiles();


            // Calling recursive method
            RecursivePrint(arr, 0, fileName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -Xmx to allocate more memory for your jvm. For more information please refer https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space.

Comment: increasing xmx wont solve the problem ....i tried it.The problem is when i read my C drive files